# multiple animations based on one animation

Tags: animation

i have "aim shot" animation, but I want the same animation for the "idle shot" animation changing the position of the weapon without messing up the rest of the keyframes

my rig has the bones "ik.handtarget.L" and "ik.handtarget.R" which have as parent the bone "weapon", what I want is to change from the shooting animation while aiming to a shooting animation on idle only by adding a downward offset and rotating it a bit

[image]

I have tried modifying the curves but it becomes tedious to have to modify them one by one. I would like to know if there is a simpler method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry, english is not my native language, try to be as brief as possible so as not to confuse anyone.